# Does "local variables are thread safe" come with a condition?

Tags: java, multithreading

In another thread I came across this question, so I have to put it here as a simple and focused question.

```
void method(){

   Machine machine = new Machine();
   ...
}

class Machine{
   private static Tool tool = new Tool();    
   ...
}
```

Although Machine is a local variable in method(), it's still thread unsafe because Machine has a static instance variable 'tool' that could be potentially thread unsafe, since all threads will share this 'tool' object  due to static.

So if Machine is thread safe by itself through whatever way, then it can be safely stated that "the local variable machine" is thread safe. Otherwise, it's not safe, even though 'machine' is a local variable.

Is this understanding correct?

Comment: "Although Machine is a local variable in method" - it is not, it is a class, an object of type Class, and resides somewhere in the heap. 
"machine" indeed is a local variable, but it holds only a reference to the object of type Machine made with the expression "new Machine()", while the object itself again lies in the heap, as any other object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this understanding is correct. Only the variable itself is thread-safe, in the sense that other threads will not modify its value concurrently.

This protection does not extend to the object referenced by your local variable: depending on the object's inner construction, such as mutability and use of static variables, the object may or may not be thread-safe.

Note that local variables of primitive types and local variables referencing immutable objects are always thread-safe.

Comment: So it seems to me the claim "local variables are thread safe" doesn't make much sense, since many times you still have to make sure the local object created in the method is thread safe. That doesn't make much difference from other variables.

Comment: @user697911 It makes sense because if you put something in a local variable, you don't have to think about synchronizing access to it, because other threads cannot access it anyway. If you put something in an instance variable, you must think about synchronization in concurrent environments. That's in addition to thinking about the content of the class referenced by your variable, which remains a concern for both local variables and instance variables.

Comment: @dasblinklight's: what is the usual way to make the static variable thread safe in this example?

Comment: @martin Make it `final` if you can; use synchronized methods or an explicit lock if you must write to it.

Comment: @user697911, The claim, "local variables are thread safe" is absolutely and unambiguously true.  They are thread safe because it is impossible for one Java thread to access the local variables of a different thread.  If you find the claim to be at all confusing or misleading or unsatisfying, then that probably means that you still do not fully appreciate what "local variable" means.

Comment: @user697911, if a local variable refers to an object that is "created in the method," and if the method does not share the object reference with any other thread (e.g., by copying the reference to a `static` variable or, by copying the reference into a shared container,) then the thread-safety of the object is irrelevant.  An object that is only used by one thread does not _need_ to be thread-safe.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the *statement local variables are thread safe* comes with a couple of conditions.

Firstly, let's look at why local variables are thread safe. This is because **the variables are allocated on the method's own stack frame**, which is NOT shared with any other execution path.

So, it is important to note that the variable itself is thread-safe, NOT necessarily what it points to. In other words:

- Primitive variables are completely thread safe, because the value is on the stack itself
- Object references is a more complicated story, because the actual object is created on the heap and the stack frame just points to the heap memory.

In the image below, the integer variable is thread safe but the Object and Array are not.
[image]

Whether the object is thread-safe entirely depends on whether the class is designed to be thread-safe or not.

Comment: I am interested in this question too. So what's the usual way to make Machine or Tool thread safe so that method() will be safe in this situation?

Comment: martin, the simplest starting point would to be used the *synchronized* keyword to protect any methods of the Tool class that modify state. Please see http://winterbe.com/posts/2015/04/30/java8-concurrency-tutorial-synchronized-locks-examples for detailed examples.

Comment: Is there way to make the whole Tool safe, without going into looking at each of its method? Because sometimes assuming here the Tool comes from an external library, and I had such a situation.

Comment: @RajeshKolappakam, what tool do you use to draw this beautiful graph?

Comment: @martin, two solutions:  (1) Let each thread have its own `Tool`.  That way, it doesn't need to be thread-safe.  (2) If the threads must use a shared `Tool`, then let them also share a [`Lock`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Lock.html).  Make sure that all of the threads lock the `Lock` before using the `Tool.`

Answer (score 1):

> So if Machine is thread safe by itself through whatever way, then it can be safely stated that "the local variable machine" is thread safe.

It can always and unconditionally be stated that the 'local variable `machine`' is thread-safe', regardless of the thread-safety of any object it refers to.

> Otherwise, it's not safe, even though 'machine' is a local variable.

If 'it' refers to the local variable, it is always thread-safe.

> Is this understanding correct?

No. You are confusing variables with objects.

- Local variables, such as `machine` in your example, are thread-safe, period.
- Objects are or are not thread-safe depending on what's inside them, regardess of where and how they are referenced, i.e. in this case whether or not the *object* that is an instance of `Machine` is referenced by the local variable `machine`.

Comment: Local variable is safe, which doesn't mean too much. What matters is the object it refers to. So most likely even for local variables, thread safety is still a top concern.

Comment: @user697911 That's what I said. Local variables are thread-safe, and that's the answer to the question, which is, and I quote, 'does “local variables are thread safe” come with a condition?' I've answered the part about the object referred to as well.